# Define function that takes jpeg image and save it as array

Tags: python, arrays

Im trying to make a function which needs as input an image file in jpg format and outputs an array every time i call it. This is what i achieved so far:

```
import scipy.misc as sm
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def imagefunc(image):
    try:
        i = Image.open(image)
        if i.format == 'jpg':
            return i.format == 'jpg'
    except OSError:   # Checking for different possible errors in the input file
        print ('This is not a jpg image! Input has to be a jpg image!')
        return False 
    except FileNotFoundError:   # Another check for error in the input file
        print ('No image was found! Input file has to be in the same directory as this code is!')
        return False

    imgarray = np.array(sm.imread(image, True))
    return imgarray
```

The problem is that when i call it, "imagefunc(kvinna)" to open a jpeg picture it outputs: NameError: name 'kvinna' is not defined. What am i missing here? Is the code wrong or is it file directory problem? Thanks

Comment: try with `kvinna.jpeg`

Comment: Make sure the directory of a image is same as your script. You also should use quotation marks and format when calling a function, so it should looke like this: `imagefunc('kvinna.jpg')`

Comment: @JJAACCEeEKK, oh stupid me, that was the problem. Thanks alot. Now i understand why this question got a vote down lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reading and Writing Images](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/tutorial.html#reading-and-writing-images)

You are not opening the image correctly, hence the `Name Error`

```
i = Image.open(image) # image should be "image_name.ext"
```

here `image` should be **"kvinna.jpeg"** with the extension.

so the function call will be: `imagefunc("kvinna.jpeg")` further check or either *jpeg* or *jpg* in your function definition.

`Image.open(image)` returns an Image object, later check the extension for it.